# Navigation Back Button is not visible in View Controller

Tags: objective-c, back-button

I have used custom back button in view controller .But it is not visible.Please help me with this.
Here is my code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSMutableAttributedString * attributedString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"GDPR Privacy Policy"];
    [attributedString addAttribute: NSLinkAttributeName value: @"https://privacypolicies.com/privacy/view/f5904d8b8bf9b0064592688552be71bc" range: NSMakeRange(0, attributedString.length)];
    self.lbl.attributedText = attributedString;
    self.Background_View.layer.cornerRadius = 10;
    self.Background_View.layer.borderWidth = 1;
    self.Background_View.layer.borderColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;

    self.navigationItem.leftItemsSupplementBackButton = YES;
    [StaticHelper setLocalizedBackButtonForViewController:self];
     // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


- (IBAction)back_action_btn:(id)sender
{
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

[image: My Storyboard]

Answer (score 1):

You always see the back button of the *previous* view controller. If you push another view controller on top of this one, *then* you will see this back button.

Comment: how to do that . please help me do to

Answer (score -1):

Well you cannot add a custom back button on default navigation bar. You have to take a UIView on the StoryBoard or Xib file and add a custom back button using interface builder or programatically. I am proving an image for your kind consideration so you will have an idea regarding this. 
Thanks
[image]